# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: c#, mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

ill get straight to the point.I have two tables:

1. Customer info
2. Orders

now since a customer can have 0 or more order I created a relation between these two tables using Index. In parent table company name is Primary key and in order company name is index.

1. I know that the data types and size and engines should be the same.
2. I also know that the company name should exist in parent table in order that we can modify the child table.

I've doubled checked all of them but i still get the error in c#

> "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtgCart.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO order_info (CompanyName,Order_ID,ProductName,Model,Address,Quantity,Price) VALUES(@CompanyName,@Order_ID,@ProductName,@Model,@Address,@Quantity,@Price)";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName",dtgCart.Rows[i].Cells["CompanyName"]);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order_ID", dtgCart.Rows[i].Cells["Order_ID"]);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", dtgCart.Rows[i].Cells["ProductName"]);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", dtgCart.Rows[i].Cells["Model"]);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", dtgCart.Rows[i].Cells["Address"]);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity",dtgCart.Rows[i].Cells["Quantity"]);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price",dtgCart.Rows[i].Cells["Price"]);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
Con.Close(); 
Con.Dispose();
```

this is the code that insert data to the child table

[image: Relation Designer view]

should i use SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; if i do what are the drawbacks 
thank you in advance

Comment: Did you check in debugger value of `dtgCart.Rows[i].Cells["CompanyName"]`?

Comment: You are trying to insert into `order_info` but the `CompanyName` does not exist in the `Customerinfo` table so the query fails.

Comment: @CodingYoshi CompanyName is PK

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Yes I get that. But it needs to exist if the OP is trying to insert orders for that customer. That is why the error is being thrown.

Comment: @CodingYoshi there is a row in 'Customerinfo' which consist of a customer info with the name "Baron Emperor" . now when I try to add an order to 'order_info' with the same name i get the error

Comment: Mansour then you should do what @SergeyBerezovskiy asked you to do in the first comment above. It is possible that one of the values does not exist in the `Customerinfo` table.

Comment: The drawback of using `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` is that you completely default the purpose of having a foreign key; if you are sure the referenced value is present, make sure the referenced value does not have any leading/trailing whitespace or non-printing characters that are not always obvious.

Comment: @CodingYoshi the problem was that there is no more  'dtgCart.Rows[i].Cells["CompanyName"].text);' instead i used  ,dtgCart.Rows[i].Cells["CompanyName"].Value); and it worked but i cant insert 2 rows with same company name this one is really newbiew question but why it is index i should be able to

Comment: Okay this is getting weird , when the data get inserted after that i get this error Column 'CompanyName' cannot be null

Comment: You should be able to insert many rows with the same companyname but the `Order_ID` has to be unique. Also make sure you have not specified for `CompanyName` to be unique in the `order_info` table.

Comment: How is that weird? If `CompanyName` is null, then who will the order be for? That is correct. Please read a tutorial on primary and foreign keys. You need to get a better grasp on those.

Comment: thank you everyone i solved it all of the problems, god bless yall

Comment: @CodingYoshi the problem was that I'm inserting from data grid view and when I have 1 row in it , it also counts the next empty row so all i did was  '      for (int i = 0; i < dtgCart.Rows.Count; i++)' instead of this i did      'for (int i = 0; i < dtgCart.Rows.Count-1; i++)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code Works Now

```
      for (int i = 0; i < dtgCart.Rows.Count-1; i++)
      {
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO order_info (CompanyName,Order_ID,ProductName,Model,Address,Quantity,Price) VALUES(@CompanyName,@Order_ID,@ProductName,@Model,@Address,@Quantity,@Price)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName",dtgCart.Rows[i].Cells["CompanyName"].Value);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order_ID", dtgCart.Rows[i].Cells["Order_ID"].Value);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", dtgCart.Rows[i].Cells["ProductName"].Value);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", dtgCart.Rows[i].Cells["Model"].Value);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", dtgCart.Rows[i].Cells["Address"].Value);
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity",dtgCart.Rows[i].Cells["Quantity"].Value);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price",dtgCart.Rows[i].Cells["Price"].value);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  Con.Close(); 
            Con.Dispose();
```